# Mongoose get current data even it's not valid with the model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I changed two properties in my User.model:

```
address: [
   {
      street: String,
      number: Number,
      city: String,
      country: String
}],
phone: [
   {
      landLine: String,
      mobilePhone: String
}]
```

to only a object:

```
address:{
      street: String,
      number: Number,
      city: String,
      country: String
},
phone:{
      landLine: String,
      mobilePhone: String
}
```

However, there are still some users which holds an array on it. So I created an script to update those users, but when using `User.find({})`, the phone and address property are `undefined`. I guess that is because that there are not valid with the current model.

Since `user.address` and `user.phone` are both `undefined`, the data object will only contain 2 empty objects for phone and address which results in users without address and phone.

This is the code which I use for getting and updating the users:

```
function updateUser(id, data){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>{
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            {_id: id},
            {
                $set: data
            }
        ).exec( (err, res) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            return resolve();
        })
    })
}

module.exports.updateUsers = (req, res) => {
    Users.find({}).exec( (err, users) => {
    //For testing, update only 1 user
    //User.find({username: 'some@emailaddress'}).exec( (err, users) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).json({message: "Error getting users"})

        return blueBird.mapSeries(users, (user) => {

            let data = {
                address: {},
                phone: {}
            }

            if(user.address && user.address.length > 0){
                data.address = user.address[0];
            }
            if(user.phone && user.phone.length > 0){
                data.phone = user.phone[0];
            }

            return updateUser(user._id, data);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(200).json({ status: true, message: "Users are updated" });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            return res.status(500).json({ status: false, message: "Some error occured while code execute.", error: e });
        })
    })
}
```

How can I get the current data from the model without validation from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should revert your `address` and `phone` Schema, and create temporary fields (like `tmpAddress` and `tmpPhone`) with you new Object schema like this :

```
address: [{
    street: String,
    number: Number,
    city: String,
    country: String
}],
phone: [{
    landLine: String,
    mobilePhone: String
}],
tmpAddress: {
    street: String,
    number: Number,
    city: String,
    country: String
},
tmpPhone: {
    landLine: String,
    mobilePhone: String
}
```

And then you save your new fields like this :

```
data.tmpAddress = user.address[0];
data.tmpPhone = user.phone[0];
```

Once this is done, you can rewrite your `address` and `phone` Fields with Object Schema, copy tmpAddress -> address and tmpPhone -> phone, and delete tmpAddress and tmpPhone fields.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is the fastest way for now I think. I changed the script to copy the values to `tmpAddress` and `tmpPhone`, and changed some pages to use that value. After deployment we can change it back to their real names, change the script and run it again.